# std::partial_sum and Kahan algorithm

Tags: algorithm, c++11, stl

In C++11 I want to calculate the partial sum of a vector using std::partial_sum.

```
std::vector<double> vec = {-1.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1};
std::partial_sum(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin());
```

Unfortunatelly, the last entry of the resulting vector is 1.38778E-16 due to rounding errors of doubles and the fact that 0.1 has no exact presentaion as double.

```
vec = {-1.0, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 1.38778E-16};
```

Is there any chance to use the Kahan algorithm in std::partial_sum to reduce rounding errors and get a smaller error - something like

```
std::partial_sum(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin(), KahanSum);
```

Comment: Are you OK with passing a function with side effects as the operation (namely updating the running compensation term)?

Comment: Yes, that would be okay!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement Kahan summation on top of `std::partial_sum` (based on [Wikipedia pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm)):

```
double c = 0.0;
std::partial_sum(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin(),
        [c](double sum, double elem) mutable -> double {
            double y = elem - c;
            double t = sum + y;
            c = (t - sum) - y;
            return t;
        });
```

This still won't get you zero though, since `(double)0.1` is exactly equal to
`0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625` and so the exact sum of your array is about `5.5511151231E-17` (assuming standard `double`).

Comment: Great, excatly what I wanted. Didn't know about mutable. Thank you!

Comment: For VS2010 I had to add a "-> double" after the mutable keyword.

Comment: Added that in. It is necessary in C++11 - as opposed to C++14. I'm quite surprised that neither clang nor gcc warn about this.